# Can you have 2 or more billing addresses in Magento2 for one customer?

Tags: magento2, billing-address

Is there a setting in the admin? I know there is one for shipping addresses... I know theoretically one customer can have one or more addresses, but does it even make sense to have more than one billing address? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, wanted to know what is your view on this?
did you implement multiple BILLING addresses?

Answer (score 0):

> but does it even make sense to have more than one billing address?

Well, it depends. As far as I know, banks allow you to have only one billing address per credit card. If you are going to allow splitting the payment into more than one credit card, it might make sense to have more than one billing address.

That being said, Magento doesn't allow to have more than one billing address out-of-the-box.